# Meta tag content says text/html but the file is php?

Tags: php, html, seo

i understand that web pages at the end are html, css and javascript and some xml
but they still render like this `www.lalala.com/lala.php`

i have implemented this meta tag as a reach out to SEO on my final project

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

but i wanna know for sure if this is the best thing to do when all my pages are `.php`
i used to have this:
   `<meta charset="utf-8">`

but im not aware of what exactly this part contributes to? `content="text/html;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not a type of content, it's a scripting language that runs on the server. It generates output, typically HTML, although it can be other things (you can have a PHP script that sends an image file to the browser).

You probably don't need the `meta` tag to indicate that it's HTML, as that's probably the webserver's default Content-Type for PHP scripts. But you may need the tag to specify the `charset` attribute.

Comment: The `refresh` tag is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 1):

If a URL ends with `.php`, then it usually refers to resource that the server will generate from a PHP file (which it locates on the basis of the URL as a whole); the server processes any PHP commands in the file, which may cause data to be modified or inserted, and finally it sends the resulting data to the browser. And it will announce the data as being of media type text/html, or at least it should.

So there is no need to tell the browser in a `meta` tag that it’s HTML. That would be rather paradoxical, since to recognize the tag, the browser must already have worked on the assumption that the data is HTML!

A `meta` tag is useful for a different purpose: to tell the character encoding. The information should of course match the actual encoding, which in turn depends on how you use PHP. For the purpose, the tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

have identical meaning and effect. The latter is just shorter. It is recognized by all browsers and being made official in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. its show the results with the HTMl.

on the web page only show the HTML.

in the meta tag, we are using the meta for the SEO and the content type **text/html**.

because on the page we are only show the data in text or HTML format.